# Behavior of OS and ECUM after a hard and soft reset in AUTOSAR

Tags: operating-system, initialization, reset, autosar

I want to understand how OS behaves after a hard reset and a soft reset in AUTOSAR environment.

In case of normal wakeup or during startup routine.. OS init task will execute first  followed by periodic tasks.If there is a soft reset(triggered by watchdog for example) will the Init task execute again?

Comment: Please [edit] this to turn it into a single focused question. I.e. pick one of the questions you asked and keep the others for later. You could make several additional quetsions immediatly, but I recommend to first get some experience with asking good questions, with the first one. Have alook at [tour], [ask]. Try to avoid asking question which could be contered by comments pointing you  to parts of the documentation; though I admit that finding something in AUTOSAR documentation is quite hard.

Comment: I read at least the following different questions: "Is my understanding of startup correct?", "Sequence after reset?", Persistence?", "Persistence especially of stack data?". When you arrive at the last one, you might want to explain what you mean by stack data.

Comment: You might want to refer to the ECUM state diagram as background for your question: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_ECUStateManager.pdf page 30.

Comment: More official link to doc, but inside a zip: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/Releases_TEMP/Classic_Platform_4.3.1/ModeManagement.zip or even more official from here, under "mode management" https://www.autosar.org/standards/classic-platform/classic-platform-431/

Comment: user2538554 it is a pity that you don't accept my feedback. I was itching to answer the first of your questions...